# Same nodes, different colerings in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a simple directed graph in Graphviz with two kinds of nodes and edges. Each kind has it's own color. My problem is, that I would like to keep how the graph is drawn, but just change the colors. However, when I swap the node names within the two node definitions, the graph changes its layout.

```
node [shape = circle, width = 0.95, fixedsize = true, style = filled, fillcolor = palegreen] 3 "4-5" 7 "8-9" 10 18 19
node [shape = circle, width = 0.95, fixedsize = true, style = filled, fillcolor = grey]  11 12 "13-14"
```

Is there a way to force it to one static layout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **order** in which the nodes are defined does have an impact on the layout.

If you want to keep the layout and change only the colors of the nodes, then you'll need to **keep the order** of (first) appearance of the nodes and only change their `fillcolor` attribute.

For example:

```
digraph g {
  node [shape = circle, width = 0.95, fixedsize = true, style = filled, fillcolor = palegreen];
  3;
  "4-5";
  7;
  "8-9";
  10 [fillcolor = grey];
  18;
  19;
  // new default fillcolor
  node [fillcolor = grey];
  11;
  12 [fillcolor = palegreen];
  "13-14";
}
```

Resulting in

[image: fillcolor nodes]

You can specify the **default attributes** using the `node [fillcolor = grey]` instruction, and **override the default values** on a specific node if needed (`12 [fillcolor = palegreen]`).